# How to know the which javascript file is responsible for which logic in web page

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I want little help in web page debugging.
I have an xhtml page in which various javascript files are embedded where logics are written.
Now if i have to enhance the functionality of web page then how can i know which javascript file is responsible for which functionality.
How to get the flow if the code is very massive say for example in one xhtml page 20 scripts are embedded
Currently using firebug debugging tool

Comment: Use breakpoints in firebugs JS debugger. It'll tell you what file you're looking at when it hits the point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if i am not at all knowing that which js file is responisble for which feature of the web page then where will i set the breakpoint? Say for example if i have the button in my web page which works on certain conditions written in js files, now i have to enhance the conditions then how to seacrh for that particular js file.

Comment: What feature is failing? If you don't know where you or someone else implemented a specific feature, that's a problem.

Comment: Yes exactly.. somebody else has implemented that feature..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way. You have to go through all over the `JS` script to trace the flow. Normally in most browser, it will tell you what's wrong with the code. Perhaps it conflict everywhere. Try spend your time to remove one by one to see how is the code flowing through your webpage